# Nested HTML table styling

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem.

My rough HTML schema is

```
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <a>
            <div class="navbar-link">{{key}}</div>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="middle">{{val1.componentname}}</td>
                <td style="border: 1px solid #ddd;"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"></td>
                <td>{{data[temp][0].value[key][0].buildDate}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to extend my this table so as to fit with the remaining columns of the parent table.

```
P1|P2|P3             |P4|P5|P6 ---Parent table columns
C1|C2|C3|C4|C5|C6
```

Now i have to fit C4,C5,C6 under P4,P5,P6.
But C3,C4,C5,C6 is under a table which is created under P3

How to achieve this using CSS styling.

Thanks.
Sajesh

Comment: try setting table width 100%

Comment: can you create your re-problem in http://jsfiddle.com

Comment: jsfiddle link is //jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/qJTgw/8/ now i want foo2,foo3,foo4 under P2,P3,P4...

Comment: why are you using a nested table when you want the items of `<td>` of inner table under the rows of parent table?

Answer (score 1):

As per the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sajesh1985/qJTgw/8/)** posted in the comments, you can achieve this by adding the `colspan` attribute to the parent (`<td>`) of inner table with a value of **4** (i.e. *number of columns it spans across*) like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td >
            P1
        </td>
        <td >
            P2
        </td>
        <td >
            P3
        </td>
        <td >
            P4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height: 100%; min-height: 100%" colspan="4"> <!-- add colspan attribute here -->
            <table style="height: 100%; min-height: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>foo1</td>
                    <td>foo2</td>
                    <td>foo3</td>
                    <td>foo4</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJTgw/9/)**.